# MySql - Selecting First And Last Row (Not Min/Max)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table with daily stock market data in the following order:

```
_date, _opening_price, _high_price, _low_price, _close_price
```

I'm trying to transform this data into weekly data by using:

```
SELECT
MAX(_date) AS _date,
WEEK(_date) AS weeknum,
_opening_price,
MAX(_high_price) AS _high_price,
MIN(_low_price) AS _low_price,
_closing_price
FROM myTable
GROUP BY weeknum ORDER BY _date;
```

How do I select _opening_price so that it is the first _opening_price from within that week's daily data? Likewise, how do I select _closing_price so that it is the last _closing_price within the week's daily data?

Here's an example:

[image: Google Stock Market Data - MSFT]

For week ending 2007-01-05, the opening_price should be taken from 2007-01-03 (red) and the closing price should be taken from 2007-01-05 (green). Similarly, for week ending on 2007-01-12, opening price should be from 2007-01-08 and closing price from 2007-01-12.

Comment: Are you aware that `WEEK` probably won't work as you hope if you cross a year boundary?

Comment: Yes - I just posted WEEK on here for simplicity. The complete query is actually CONCAT(WEEK(_date), '-', YEAR(_date)) AS weeknum.

Comment: I don't think that will work either. :-( Though of course it depends on what you want to happen - if you *want* your weeks to be split in two when the year changes then I guess it works...

Comment: Yikes, I just realized what you're saying - if a week overlaps the year boundary, that wouldn't work. Thanks for pointing that out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, figured this one out - YEARWEEK function seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(a._date) weekending, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN a._date = b.mindate THEN a._opening_price END) openingprice,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a._date = b.maxdate THEN a._closing_price END) closingprice
FROM myTable a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(YEAR(_date), '-', WEEK(_date)) weeknum, 
        MIN(_date) mindate, 
        MAX(_date) maxdate
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY weeknum
) b ON a._date IN (b.mindate, b.maxdate)
GROUP BY b.weeknum
```

Comment: Thanks, Zane. This did the job!